# Add Bean Validation for a Converter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I would like to use validation for a converter bean, but I get the following error

```
 HV000151: A method overriding another method must not redefine the parameter constraint configuration, but method StringToFooConverter#convert(String) redefines the configuration of Converter#convert(Object).
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.rule.OverridingMethodMustNotAlterParameterConstraints.apply(OverridingMethodMustNotAlterParameterConstraints.java:24)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.ExecutableMetaData$Builder.assertCorrectnessOfConfiguration(ExecutableMetaData.java:462)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.ExecutableMetaData$Builder.build(ExecutableMetaData.java:380)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.BeanMetaDataBuilder$BuilderDelegate.build(BeanMetaDataBuilder.java:260)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.BeanMetaDataBuilder.build(BeanMetaDataBuilder.java:133)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManagerImpl.createBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManagerImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManagerImpl.getBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManagerImpl.java:165)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:267)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:235)
```

Converter

```
   @Validated
public class StringToFooConverter implements Converter<String, Foo> {

   @Override
   public Foo convert( @NotNull final String source ) {
      return new Foo( source );
   }
}
```

Config

```
   @Bean
   public StringToFooConverter stringToFooConverter() {
      return new StringToFooConverter();
   }
```

What is wrong?

EDIT:

Add a example and what iam tried.
https://github.com/MelleD/spring-bean-validation-example

Interface and DTO is generated by open api generator. So currently not changeable.

Comment: Don't mix conversion and validation those are seperate concepts. If you are using this for a controller there are different and better ways to do this.

Comment: Yes this used for a controller, but on method level it's not possible because you cannot override the method for a interface. I add a RestController

Comment: Use `Foo` as a method argument, not a `String`. Something like `@Valid @PathVariable Foo foo). Also your controller, regarding a URL doesn't really make sense. Or in your case you want a `URL` just use that directly.

Comment: Wait i add a example. The Beans/DTOs and rest controller interfaces is generated by open api so it's not possible to change this. You can just add a String or UUID for a path variable

Comment: Spring uses the converters to convert from a `String` to whatever you need in your method. Using your generation framework as an excuse is a poor excuse imho. Still you shouldn't mix validation and conversion as those are different things. If you want different code, write a different contract as that contract leads to workarounds for something that is supported out-of-the-box.

Comment: Where is the rule that you should not mix validation and conversion? Link?
Validation and conversion are related and i can add a second validation service which makes the same or i can add the autowire the Validator and validate it this will also work.

Comment: Different concepts, responsibilities imho basic design but we can agree to disagree. Fact remains is that your contract/generation framework puts you in a position you need to find a solution for a problem you wouldn't have without that framework. As stated without that crappy api it would just work (with a simple converter (or maybe even without one) and an annotation). Now you  need to work around the defaults because you are using a framework (or contract) that forces you out of that default functionality.

Comment: Well, it's not that dramatic either. I can just register a bean without an interface  then it does.

`public Foo validateAndConvert( NotNull Size( min = 1, max = 256 ) ValidFoo final String source ) {
      return Foo.fromUrn( source );
   }`
this will work as well. Thought there is smarter solution with the converter framework.